# unknown method in REST API in CODEIGNITER

Tags: php, rest, codeigniter

When I try to load the form data in browser it shows this error

> **{"":"Unknown method"}**

HOW TO SOLVE

This is the controller code in REST API using Codeigniter.

Help me to get out from this problem.......

```
require(APPPATH.'/libraries/REST_Controller.php');

class Api extends REST_Controller{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
      //  $this->CI->lang->load('form_validation');
        $this->load->model('book_model');
        $this->load->helper('url');

    }

    public function view_get(){
        $this->load->helper('form');    

    }
    public function display_post(){
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->view('add');
    }
}
```

Add.php code is here, I want to display the data in webpage through the controller but when I run this code it shows an error

> **{"":"Unknown method"}**

url: **http://localhost/code-restfullAPI/index.php/API/display**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form method="POST" action="<?php site_url('index.php/Api/addBook_post'); ?>">

Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="name" >
<br>
Price:<br>
<input type="text" name="price" >
<br>
Author:<br>
<input type="text" name="author" >
<br>
Category:<br>
<input type="text" name="category" >
<br>
Language:<br>
<input type="text" name="language" >
<br>
ISBN:<br>
<input type="text" name="isbn" >
<br>
Publish Date:<br>
<input type="text" name="publish_date" >
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Add">
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: To access `display`, the request must be a `POST` request (you've literally added that, the `_post` part) while the browser uses `GET` to access URL's.

Comment: so what i need to do here for running the code in browser

Comment: If you want to be able to access that method through the browser directly, try and define it as a `GET` method. Rename it to `display_get()`

Comment: its working but when submit the form again it shows the same error what i do, help me

Comment: Of course. You need to decide if you should be able to access that page using POST or GET. If you need to access it through both, create two methods, one `display_post()` and one `display_get()`. I don't see why you should be able to access it through GET though, since I'm guessing it's handling the form data (which doesn't exist if you go directly to the end point)? I also don't get what your form have to do with anything.

Comment: can i change post to get in the form

Comment: The form should be POST. Today you have a `display_post()`, add another method called `display_get()` that does the same (or even calls `display_post()`). FYI, this isn't really a RESTAPI if you're returning html forms etc.

Comment: then how can i handle it in restapi

Comment: You need to do some research about what a RESTful API is. There are _plenty_ of tutorials out there. The question is way too broad for SO.

Comment: do you know any sites for restapi tutorials?? if you know please tell me

Comment: Yes, google.com has a bunch. Asking for tutorials are off-topic here and like I said, there are _plenty_ out there, if you just search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

site_url('index.php/Api/addBook_post');

remove "_post" from addBook_post

Comment: do you have any authentication scheme ??